# Node and PDFKit - how to separate PDF generation business logic from router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-pdfkit

I am working on a web app using Express and Node.js. The `api` router currently has a GET method `generatePDF` to generate a PDF with PDFKit library.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

router.get('/generatePDF', async function(req, res, next) {
    var text = req.params.text;

    var myDoc = new PDFDocument({bufferPages: true});

    let buffers = [];

    myDoc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
    myDoc.on('end', () => {
        let pdfData = Buffer.concat(buffers);
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(pdfData),
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=report.pdf'
        }).end(pdfData);
    });

    const lorem = text;

    myDoc.fontSize(8);    

    myDoc.text(`This text is left aligned. ${lorem}`, {
        align: 'left'
    });

    myDoc.moveDown();
    myDoc.text(`This text is centered. ${lorem}`, {
        align: 'center'
    });

    myDoc.moveDown();
    myDoc.text(`This text is right aligned. ${lorem}`, { 
        align: 'right'
    });

    myDoc.moveDown();
    myDoc.text(`This text is justified. ${lorem}`, { 
        align: 'justify'
    });

    myDoc.end();
});
```

It is not a best practice to mix the business logic with the controller (router) as the web app grows, also also from the reusability point of view. I am new to PDFKit and wondering how I can separate the PDFKit part into a separate Javascript `PDFGenerator.js` and make it called by the router by including:

```
const PDFGenerator = require('../PDFGenerator');
```